# How to get value of application variable in JavaScript from asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to access the value of an application variable in JavaScript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a public property in codebehind.

```
public string firstName = "Sanju";
```

Access this in JavaScript like this.

```
    <script>
        var myName;
        function GetMyName()
        {
            myName = <%=this.firstName%>
        }
    </script>
```

To Access value in Session State, use this.

```
            myName = '<%=Session["firstName"]%>'
```

To Access value in Application State, use this.

```
            myName = '<%=Application["firstName"]%>'
```

Comment: Thanks But i wants to access value of Application Variable in javascript not my pages public variable.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable public to access in javascript.

In code behind.

```
public string YourVar = "hello";
```

In javascript

```
alert("<%= YourVar  %>");
```

Note the value of the server side variable is substituted in generated html / javascript once the response is sent. If you want to access it from javascript after page is loaded then you might need to use [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to fetch value from server.

Comment: thanks for Reply me.My code is like
Application["Test"] = Some value.My Query is that i wants access value of this Application variables in javascript.How can i access it Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The following gets the `ClientID` of the rendered control

```
//markup
<asp:TextBox ID="aTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="bTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="cTextBox" runat="server" />

//script
var Members =
{
    aTextBox: $("#<%=aTextBox.ClientID %>"),
    bTextBox: $("#<%=bTextBox.ClientID %>"),
    cTextBox: $("#<%=cTextBox.ClientID %>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Sessions...
Make a session in your class (I assume you have a General class)and use its reference to access it on any page you want. But remember you have to assign a value before using it.

e.g,

below is a session of UserID.

```
public static int UserId
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = value;
    }
}
```

First you have to store value in your session as soon as you application starts.

```
User user = new user(); // consider you have a User class

protected void btnLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _user.Username = this.txtUserName.Text;
    _user.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;

    if (_user.Validate())
    {
       General.UserID = _user.UserID;  // here you are storing the id of logged in user
       Response.Redirect("~/HomePage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
       this.labelNotice.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
    }
}
```

To access the value of this session on any page in javascript,

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Models" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myID;
    function GetMyID() {
        myID= '<%=General.UserId%>';
    }
</script>
```

I imported my **General** class which is placed in the **Models** folder in **MyProject** solution.